# Can I store a pointer to non-existing data without invoking undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, pointers, undefined-behavior

I have a pointer that sometime ago pointed to alive object, but now this object is dead. Is it true, that if I don't use this dead object (don't dereference pointer, don't use methods, etc) there is no undefined behavior?

Code example:

```
int* x = new int;
int* y = x;
delete x;
// From now on never use *y, or y->... or something else
// that will "dereference" y.
```

Comment: Yes, but you should be very careful not to use it or not to delete it again.

Comment: After the initialization of `y` with `int* y = x;`, x and y are totally interchangeable here; that you freed the memory `x` points to through `x` and not through `y` is irrelevant. You could have said as well `delete y`. Dereferencing either one is equally bad.

Comment: Yes, I know. This is just an example. My particular use case is much more reasonable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is NO undefined behavior in your code. What you get are two *dangling pointers*, i.e. `x` and `y`. They are perfectly fine if you don't dereference them (or free them again), but they represent a major source of errors in C-style code.

Comment: But there are good chances that soon or later it will come ;)

Answer (score 2):

It's absolutely fine. A simpler, and more familiar, case is

```
int* x = new int;
delete x;
```

The behaviour on dereferencing `x` is undefined and some programmers will write `delete x; x = nullptr;` to emphasise this.

Acknowledge @BoPersson, reading `x` following the `delete` is, at best, implementation defined, and could include a hardware trap for an invalid address. See [Is it legal to compare dangling pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30694069/is-it-legal-to-compare-dangling-pointers)

Comment: As it turns out here [Is it legal to compare dangling pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30694069/is-it-legal-to-compare-dangling-pointers) reading the value of a dangling pointer is at best implementation-defined (C++14) and could include a hardware trap for an invalid address.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent this case happen, you can use

```
std::shared_ptr
std::weak_ptr
```

But if you want to create this scenario in your program, can you tell why? normally we assume the program is always in good state

Comment: My use case is very specific. Long story short: I use complicated framework. I don't manage lifetime of my classes, framework does it for me. There are two objects (as members) in my class: one has some data, the another points to the data in the first one. I was wondering if I can declare them in any order or not (because they will be deleted in the reverse order comparing to their declaration).