# Inserting addresses into sets, the size of the sets is smaller than expected

Tags: c++, set

I am getting a size of 1. Shouldn't it be 4? I am inserting the addresses of integers into the sets.

```
void func(set<int*>& s1, set<int*>& s2, int a)
{
    s1.insert(&a);
    s2.insert(&a);
}

int main()
{
    set<int*> s1, s2;

    int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4;
    func(s1, s2, a);
    func(s1, s2, b);
    func(s1, s2, c);
    func(s1, s2, d);

    cout<<"  s1.size = "<<s1.size()<<"  s2.size = "<<s2.size()<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Really? 3 people think this question should be closed because it "does not appear to be about programming"?

Comment: Surprisingly, GCC (`g++ -W -Wall -Wextra -Werror`) and Clang compile this code without any warnings.

Comment: @user200783 _"... within the scope defined in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)."_

Comment: This is neither "a problem that can no longer be reproduced" nor "a simple typographical error". Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 44):

`&a` inside `func` is the address of the local parameter `a`, not the address of the original variable (`a`, `b`, `c` or `d`), which:

1. Can take various kind of values between different calls of `func`;
2. Becomes an invalid pointer once you reach the end of the scope in which `a` is declared (the end of `func` here).

In your case, since you do nothing but calling `func` 4 times in a row, the address of this parameter happens to not change, which is why you get a size of 1 (you insert the same pointer 4 times).

This behavior is [implementation defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30694069/is-it-legal-to-compare-dangling-pointers/30694084) (thanks @Rakete1111) since sets will need to compare invalid pointers.

Accessing the pointed element through `s1` or `s2` (e.g. `**s1.begin()`) is undefined behavior though.

Comment: @Holt It looks like it is [implementation defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30694084/3980929).

Comment: @Rakete1111 Thanks, I did not know that. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 28):

The parameter `a` is passed by value, that means what you're inserting is the address of the local parameter copied from the arguments. `a` will be constructed  everytime when `func` is called, their addresses might be same or different; nothing is guaranteed.

And it's worth noting that the parameter `a` will be destroyed when get out of the function, then the pointers inserted will become dangled.

You should make it pass-by-reference, then the addresses of the arguments (i.e. the variable `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` in `main()`) will be inserted. These addresses are different, and won't become dangled inside the body of `main()`.

```
void func(set<int*>& s1, set<int*>& s2, int& a)
{
    s1.insert(&a);
    s2.insert(&a);
}
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/AOTKLE21568)