# What ! (char*) means in C

Tags: c, pointers, char

I was looking at an example and I saw this:

```
char *str;

/* ... */

if (!str || !*str) {
    return str;
}
```

Does it mean it's empty or something?

Comment: In C, `!x` is equivlent to `x == 0`, always

Comment: This is a check, whether str points to anything, and whether than thing is not a null character.

Comment: I've seen this example before. This code comes from the subroutine `char* segfault_maybe(void)`.

Comment: @imallett I see. I assume that OP has just provided `char *str;` to show the original definition of `str` and in the 'real code' there is some stuff in between

Comment: Sorry about my char *str. Yeah I just want to show that str is a normal string. The is some stuff in my actual code.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, PTN, I figured as much. I typically write something like `char* str = /*something*/;` to help dissuade pedant gits like myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`str` is a char pointer. `!` negates it. Basically, `!str` will evaluate to true (1) when `str == NULL`.

The second part is saying, (if `str` points to something) evaluate to true (1) if the first character is a null char (`'\0'`) - meaning it's an empty string.

*Note:*
`*str` dereferences the pointer and retrieves the first character. This is the same as doing `str[0]`.

Comment: `!` converts it to a Boolean value, then negates the Boolean.

Comment: You mean `str == NULL`, not `*str == NULL` . And `*str` is a char, not a pointer.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yes, my mistake.

Comment: @Pushkin "char pointer" and "char" are different. `str` is a char pointer, `*str` is a char.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Oh of course. That was silly. When I wrote it, `*str` didn't mean dereferencing a pointer, but `char *str`. I wasn't clear.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: `!` yields `1` if its operand is equal to `0`, `0` otherwise. The result is of type `int`.

Answer (score 4):

`!str` means that there is no memory allocated to `str`.  `!*str` means that `str` points to an empty string.

Comment: `str = malloc( 42 ); free( str ); assert( ! str ); /* fails */`

Comment: @Potatoswatter Evaluating `str` in your the last expression causes undefined behaviour, therefore `!str` is moot. IOW If `!str` is evaluated without UB having been triggered, then it's equivalent to testing whether `str` points to allocated memory (or one past the end)

Comment: @MattMcNabb Could you let me know what UB means? I don't know that acronym.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Is that true in C? I don't see anything in §6.3.2.3 or §6.5.16.1.

Comment: I still stand by the fact that `!str` means there is no memory allocated to `str`.  That does *not* mean that `str` having a non-zero value implies that it is pointing to some allocated memory.

Comment: `!str` does imply that there is no memory allocated, but the word "means" suggests identical conditions.

Comment: @Potatoswatter see C99 6.2.4/2 and 6.2.6.1/5 . More discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024866/when-is-it-valid-to-access-a-pointer-to-a-dead-object)

Comment: @MattMcNabb Thanks. So, in fact, an implementation could implement `free` as a function-like macro (§7.1.4) which assigns `NULL` to its argument, using the latitude that the value is indeterminate. (This would require some magic to distinguish lvalues, but it would be conforming.) My assertion would not fire.

Comment: @unxnut I assume you mean "`!str` evaluating *true* means there is no memory allocated to `str`".  We were pointing out a caveat (that your answer possibly should mention) that if `str` is a dangling pointer (and therefore does not point to allocated memory), then `!str` causes undefined behaviour; so the program may appear to run as if `!str` evaluated true.

Answer (score 2):

Before asking you can do small tests.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *str = "test";
    printf("%d\n",*str);
    printf("%c\n",*str); // str[0]
    printf("%d\n",str);
    if (!str || !*str)
    {
        printf("%s",str);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

meaning of `!` is negation. Except `0` every value is true for `if` condition. Here, `str` and `*str` return values that are not `0`. So, you can make an inference.

Answer (score 0):

The first expression `!str` evaluates true if str is set to `NULL`, and false if set to anything else *regardless of whether the memory pointed to is still allocated or not*.  This can lead to undefined behavior if `str` is left set to  memory that is no longer active.

The second expression `!*str` evaluates true if the value at the address in `str` is `\0` (null character), but is not evaluated at all if `!str` evaluated true due to the short-circuiting action of the boolean OR operator.