# Memory allocation for a structure pointer

Tags: c, pointers

If there is a structure as below:

```
struct student {
    int id;
    int marks;
} *S1,S2;
```

Why is it required to allocate memory to *S1 but not to S2? When *S1 is declared as a structure pointer, is there no memory allocated to it? Is memory allocated only when we explicitly allocate?

Comment: Who said that anything was required?

Comment: Memory *is* automatically allocated for S1.  Exactly enough memory to represent a pointer.  You can point that anywhere you like, even unallocated memory, it will be a valid pointer pointing at an invalid `struct student`.

Comment: Memory for the pointer itself is allocated, but until you allocate a `student` and assign the pointer to point to the location of that memory, the pointer will be pointing to garbage if uninitialized. S2 is being allocated the same way the pointer S1 is; but one is a `student` and one is a pointer. The memory of the pointer itself and what it's pointing to are completely different things.

Comment: @Tibrogargan - That's not really a valid pointer...

Comment: Yes memory is allocated to `*S1` only when you explicitly allocate. As opposed to `S2` which is an actual `struct`,not a pointer.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth It's valid for use as a pointer.  Assigning a value to it won't cause an access violation, neither will reading the value.  What it points to may not be valid.

Comment: @Tibrogargan - In theory, it's more complicated than that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024866/when-is-it-valid-to-access-a-pointer-to-a-dead-object

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth you're implying there is no determinate way to test if a pointer is null, since if the pointer's value has become indeterminate simply reading the pointer invokes undefined behavior

Comment: @tibrogargan: don't have the spec to hand right now, but I would wager that null is defined not to be an indeterminate/trap representation.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Schrodinger's pointer.  You don't know if it's null until after you read it.  It's still undefined behavior

Comment: @tibrogargan: if there's a chance it's indeterminate (as opposed to null or pointing to a valid object) then you shouldn't be reading it.  I'm not sure what use case there'd be for that, either.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth That's exactly my point.  You are implying that there is literally no determinate way to test if a pointer is null.

Comment: @tibrogargan: only when "indeterminate" is one other possible value. You shouldn't write code where that's a possibility.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121963/discussion-between-tibrogargan-and-oliver-charlesworth).

Answer (score 3):

In C, each variable is a memory location. In your example, both S1 and S2 are variables, but, S1 happens to be a pointer. A pointer is a variable which by purpose is defined to hold the address of a memory location.

In your example S2 being a normal variable of type `struct student` points to a memory location whose size is `sizeof(struct student)`. S1 being a pointer variable points to a memory location whose size is equivalent to the size of a pointer variable (4 bytes for 32 bit systems and 8 bytes for 64 bit systems typically).

Just as you need to assign values to normal variables, you need to assign the address of a memory location to a pointer which is what you do when you allocate a memory and assign to it.

Comment: Does that mean S1 and S2 have occupy different size of memory when declared?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is how the language work. It automatically reserves memory for the type you ask for. If you ask for a `struct student`, it reserves memory for a `struct student`. If you ask for a `pointer`, it reserves memory for a `pointer`.

Example with `int`:

```
int n;  // Reserves memory for an int
int *p; // Reserves memory for a pointer (that points to an int)
        // but there is no memory allocated to hold the int
        // p needs to be initialized before you dereference it (i.e. *p)

p = malloc(sizeof(int));  // Initialize p and allocate memory to hold the int
if (!p) exit(1);          // Error - no memory available

*p = 5; // Now p can be used

free(p); // Release the memory
```

Your case is not different than the example above. S2 is a `struct student` while S1 is a pointer (to a `struct student`) and you need to initialize S1 by allocating memory for a `struct student`. Like:

```
S1 = malloc(sizeof(struct student));
```

Answer (score 0):

Each variable is associated with some storage (at least in C). So it is for `S1` and `S2`. But `S1` is a pointer, so storage for pointer to structure is required, `S2` is a structure so storage for a full structure is allocated. What makes the difference is that `S1` is an indirection, means that its storage does not contains a structure but address of a structure, if you want it to be linked to a structure you need to provide it an appropriate address. Either:

```
S1 = &S2;
```

where `&` is the operator that take the address of `S2`. Now `S1` is a link to `S2`. Or:

```
S1 = malloc(sizeof(struct student));
```

where `malloc` (dynamically) allocates a storage for a structure and returns its address (in case of success).