# free() initialising memory to 0

Tags: c, free

```
int main() 
{   
    int *p,*q;  
    p=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));   
    *p=5;   
    free(p);
}
```

When I examine the memory address allocated to `p` after the execution of the `free(p)` statement, I observe that the memory content is 0. Is this the right behavior because I have read that `free` does not initialize the memory to 0?

Comment: It does not guarantee to do so, but is allowed to. Some dynamic memory managers use the content of unallocated memory to store administration data on available memory. Being able to access it seems to be a case of luck, it could easily cause a segfault.

Comment: No need to cast the return value of malloc as its return type is void*.

Comment: This code has undefined behavior.

Comment: @MCG Aside from maybe missing `#include <...>`, what [UB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45697247/free-initialising-memory-to-0#comment78353721_45697247) are you suggesting?

Comment: @chux It's UB in a hosted environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The content of `*p` after `free(p)` returns is undefined. It may be 0, 42 or anything else.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int *p, *x;

    p = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *p = 5;

    // the following will print "0x7fd0cac00350: 5" or similar
    printf("%p: ", p);
    printf("%d\n", *p);

    free(p);

    printf("%p\n", p); // won't change from before
    printf("%d\n", *p); // UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR
}
```

Comment: I think you mean the content of `*p`.

Comment: Yes, I did. Thank you

Comment: Even dereferencing `p` is undefined, isn't it?

Comment: @Yunnosch actually, `p` will be indeterminate after `free` too.

Comment: @ikegami even *using* the value of `p` might be undefined.

Comment: @ikegami you're absolutely incorrect here.

Comment: No, `p` itself won't change, it still holds the same address returned by `malloc`. But it will probably point to uninitialized memory.

Comment: Please read and understand https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024866/when-is-it-valid-to-access-a-pointer-to-a-dead-object @ikegami

Comment: Re "*Please read and understand*", I didn't know "indeterminate" was a formal term. I assumed you meant undefined. Removed my comment.

Comment: int * p = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*10); Say each array element contains some value. After free(p) only the first 2 are initialized to 0. The rest are as it is. I am running this program on a 64 bit machine. Why this behaviour?

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073842/is-the-compiler-allowed-to-recycle-freed-pointer-variables

Comment: @Jeremy  [`p` itself won't change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45697247/free-initialising-memory-to-0#comment78353209_45697336) --> Maybe, maybe not.    Attempting to access `p` after `free(p)` is UB, until a `p = something_valid;` so code cannot insure "`p` itself won't change" nor benefit from that.

Comment: @Nitin No need to cast the return value of malloc as its return type is void*

Comment: @chux I don't see why accessing `p` itself should be UB. It's value doesn't change, thus, if `p = 0x7fd0cac00350` after malloc, it will hold the same address after `free(p)`. Dereferencing p is on another sheet of paper. I will update my answer to reflect what I meant.

Comment: @Jeremy See [The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when the object it points to reaches the end of its lifetime.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17024866/2410359) and "indeterminate value:
either an unspecified value or a trap representation" - Once `free(p)`, copying, printing, or de-referencing `p` leads to problems.  Thus code cannot certainly assess if `p`  changed value.  Example: the pointer did not change value, but `printf("%p\n", (void*) p);`  causes a trap and code dies.  So how is code to know the pointer did not change value or not?